# Qt QUrl Invalid use of incomplete type & Has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from a ftp server, then modify it and upload it again. Here is my code...

```
QNetworkAccessManager* qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://xxxxxxxxxxxx/file.txt");
url.setHost(QString("ftp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
url.setUserName(QString("xxxxxx"));
url.setPassword(QString("xxxxxxxxx"));
url.setPort(21);

connect(qnam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkReply *nReply = qnam->get(req);




void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *data) {
    QFile file("file.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        return;
    file.write(data->readAll());
    file.close();
}
```

And here are the errors:

> C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\qt\project\mainwindow.cpp:37: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QNetworkReply'
>        file.write(data->readAll());
>
> C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\qt\project\mainwindow.cpp:66: error: variable 'QUrl url' has initializer but incomplete type
>    QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/file.txt");
>
> C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\qt\project\mainwindow.cpp:66: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QUrl'
>    QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://xxxxxxxxxx/file.txt");

Thanks all.

Comment: You need to include the according header files for QNetworkReply and QUrl. Since they probably only have been forward declared, the compiler can't find the definition for them.

Comment: Seems to be the issue :) I'll try that